# How to get Sum from two tables?

Tags: c#, mysql

i have two tables first one name is "sales" and second one name is "items"
in both tables have same columns "code" and " qtd ";
i want write MYSQL query witch i need sum(qtd) from both of tables where code is same in both of tables .
for single table i am using this

"select code,sum(qtd) from sales group by code";

Comment: So you want to sum both sums?

Comment: yes i want sum from both

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "select a.code, sum(a.qtd+b.qtd) from sales a , items b where a.code=b.code  group by a.code,b.code ";

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select code, sum(qtd) 
from (
select code, qtd from sales
union all
select code, qtd from items) as innerTable
group by code
```

Comment: Sorry about that forgot the all keyword! I have edited my answer, please try that.