# How to get the Sum from three tables?

Tags: sql, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Sum from two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186036/how-to-get-sum-from-two-tables)

I have three table first "`products`" second "`items`" third "`sales`" 
The first and second tables have the same columns('`code`','`quantity`') but the third table has ('`code`','`name`') now I want sum quantity from first and second but want also want get name from third table which code is equal.
check my code

```
Select code, sum(qtd),name
from (           select a.code, a.qtd from product a
       union all select b.code, b.qtd from items   b
       union all select c.name        from sales   c where b.code=c.code
     )
group by code
```

first two giving me perfect values but third fiction giving error not showing also names.

Comment: Ask this to your classmate [How to get Sum from two tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186036/how-to-get-sum-from-two-tables)

Comment: Could You show some data from Your tables and the result You expect?

Answer (score 0):

When using `UNION` be sure that the columns you want to combine matches with each `SELECT` statement.  The first two `SELECT` statement works fine because they have the same number of columns. The third one failed because it has only one column.

---

The following are **basic rules for combining the result sets** of two (*or more*) queries by using UNION:

- The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
- The data types must be compatible.

---

From your query, I think you want like this,

```
SELECT  a.code, b.name, SUM(a.qtd) totalSUM
FROM    product a
            INNER JOIN sales b
                ON a.code = b.code
GROUP BY a.code, b.name
UNION
SELECT  a.code, b.name, SUM(a.qtd) totalSUM
FROM    items a
            INNER JOIN sales b
                ON a.code = b.code
GROUP BY a.code, b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum....

```
SELECT
  sales.name,
  (SELECT SUM(products.quantity) FROM products WHERE products.code = sales.code) as products.quantity,
  (SELECT SUM(items.quantity) FROM items WHERE items.code = sales.code) as items_quantity,
FROM sales
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this, though it's not clear what the actual requirements are:

```
select code = t1.code ,
       name = t2.name ,
       qtd  = t1.qtd 
from ( select code =      t.code   ,
              qtd  = sum( t.qtd  )
       from (           select a.code, a.qtd from product a
              union all select b.code, b.qtd from items   b
            ) t
       group by t.code
     ) t1
join sales t2 where t2.code = t1.code
```

Cheers!